# Why child element going behind container when using z-index -1

Tags: css, element, z-index, parent

I'm working inside container and I making 2 other elements parent and child. when I make child element absolute with `z-index: -1` the child going behind container. What I want is make it behind the parent.

[Js Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/w3o8sakc/4/)

```
<div class="container">
  Container<br><br>
  <div class="paremt">
    Parent position relative
    <div class="child">
      Parent child
      Position Absolute index -1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
* {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.container{
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
.paremt{
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
}
.child{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: I see it to be only behind the parent, not the container.

Comment: Default z-index value is auto, as you can see from inspect; auto sets the stack order equal to its parents. Then -1 is under every others one, so you can specify your needed z-index order for every div, to solve your problem

Comment: `position:relative;z-index:0` to container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add

```
z-index: 0;
```

to parent element. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add on your parent

```
z-index: 1;
```